# Question about why this processing of a list of lists fails

Tags: python, list

I'm wondering why this code fails...

I ask if the numeric value `1`, part of one of the `ini_list` sub component is in the list called `l`, which is a list of lists.

```
# ini_list = [[1, 2, 5, 10, 7],
# [4, 3, 4, 3, 21],
# [45, 65, 8, 8, 9, 9]]

element = 1

l = [[]]
est_dans_liste = (element in sublist for sublist in l)

if est_dans_liste:
    print("ok")
```

Note `est_dans_liste` is `is_in_list` in English.

Comment: what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: What do you think this *should* do, and why?  (Do you realize you never use `ini_list` anywhere in you code?)

Comment: you need to use any, otherwise your are just evaluating the truth value of the generator expression

Comment: `if est_dans_liste:` is *always true*. `est_dans` is a generator object, which is always truthy

Comment: More precisely `est_dans_liste` is a [*generator expression*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and your code is not evaluating it, only defining it.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, You need `.any()` like below:

```
>>> ini_list = [[1, 2, 5, 10, 7],[4, 3, 4, 3, 21],[45, 65, 8, 8, 9, 9]]
>>> element = -1
>>> [element in sublist for sublist in ini_list]
[False, False, False]
>>> any(element in sublist for sublist in ini_list)
False

>>> element = 1
>>> [element in sublist for sublist in ini_list]
[True, False, False]
>>> any(element in sublist for sublist in ini_list)
True


>>> est_dans_liste = any(element in sublist for sublist in ini_list)
>>> if est_dans_liste:
...    print("ok")
```

Comment: @deBeyssacOlivier welcome ;)